# Create array that has data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a table where all data from "treatment_parameters" is used and where parameter_fk=47. Additionally, the table should also include only the count(*) of rows from "treatment_log" where the missed_treatment=' '.

So the table should project out all data from "treatment_parameters" with parameter_fk=47 and the number of rows in "treatment_log" where missed_treatment=' '.

Should also note that: t.id = l.treatment_fk

I have attempted this, however it is partially successful. The table displays all required data, however it does not display every row from "treatment_paratmers" with parameter_fk=47. (There should be two different rows)

```html
SELECT t.id,t.parameter_fk,t.course_name,t.room, t.protocol,t.navigation,t.area,t.coil,t.number_of_treatments,t.motor_threshold,t.threshold_multiplier,t.target_threshold,t.about,t.date,t.created_at, COUNT(*) AS completed_treatments 
FROM treatment_parameters t 
LEFT JOIN treatment_log l 
ON t.id = l.treatment_fk 
WHERE t.parameter_fk = 47
AND l.missed_treatment=' '
```

Below you can see the result of the above SQL query:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoKXO.png)

However, you can see that when the SQL query is modified, there is more than just one row for paratmer_fk=47

```html
SELECT t.id,t.parameter_fk,t.course_name,t.room, t.protocol,t.navigation,t.area,t.coil,t.number_of_treatments,t.motor_threshold,t.threshold_multiplier,t.target_threshold,t.about,t.date,t.created_at 
FROM treatment_parameters t 
WHERE t.parameter_fk = 47
```

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EodeS.jpg)

So we need to show both rows, and also have the count(*) for missed_treatment=' ' effect both rows.

Below you can find the entire list from treatment_log.

[treatment_log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIQ7w.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand.  Nothing in MySQL is called "array".

Comment: I addressed the issue

Comment: It still isn't very clear. Your code asks for all rows where parameter_fk=47 AND missed_treatment is blank (or a space possibly). An example and sample data would help us understand your problem

Comment: This should 'work' if your data is as you think it is. Since there are so few records you could add sample data as text to the question.

Comment: @iainc I have updated the post please take a look!

Comment: @P.Salmon I have updated the post please take a look!

Comment: You should add treatment log - it would be helpful to add sample data as text which we can do something with rather than images.

Comment: This is Sql not JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to self-join:

```
SELECT t.id,t.parameter_fk,t.course_name,t.room, t.protocol,t.navigation,t.area,
    t.coil,t.number_of_treatments,t.motor_threshold,t.threshold_multiplier,t.target_threshold,
    t.about,t.date,t.created_at, aa.t_count AS completed_treatments 
        FROM treatment_parameters t 
        left join (select treatment_fk, count(*) as t_count from treatment_log l
         where l.missed_treatment=' ' group by treatment_fk) aa on aa.treatment_fk=t.id 
        WHERE t.parameter_fk = 47
```

Comment: This gave the following error: Unknown column 'l.missed_treatment' in 'where clause'

Comment: You are amazing! Worked!